# Using ConceptNet with Divisi reasoning Toolkit

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, corpus, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to use [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/) with the [divisi2](https://github.com/commonsense/divisi2) package. The divisi package is particularly designed for working with knowledge in semantic networks. This package takes up the graph as a input and convert it into SVD forms. With the package distribution they had provided the basic conceptNet data into graph format, this data seems to be outdated. Divisi can be used in this way [Using Divisi with conceptNet(link)](https://github.com/commonsense/divisi2/blob/master/doc/tutorial_aspace.rst). But the data needs to be updated with conceptNet5 data, is there any way to do that. Provided I have all the conceptNet data setted up locally as described in [Running your own copy](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Running-your-own-copy). So, the sqlite database I have all the data. Also I have the data into csv formats separately. So how can I load this data into Divisi package. Thanks.

Comment: Are you still interested in the answer?

Comment: yup. Will be good to know if there is any way

Comment: The best way is to ask on the mailling list. I need to do research to be able answer thougfully the question if I'm not mistaken it's along the lines of «build conceptnet with assoc-space»